# Early 2000s movie about robot that invades the world

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, soft-sci-fi

I watched this movie when I was a little kid so my memory of it is not so good. I remember there being robots that kind of look like the Iron Giant invading a city and they had these antenna things that would pop out. They also had giant mechanical bats that would dog fight with planes. I’m not sure if I’m right on this, but at the end of the movie there was a rocket about to take off from inside a mountain and was full of monkeys, but there definitely was a rocket taking off from inside a mountain.

Comment: This is a nice overall description, welcome to the site! If you remember anything else about this though do not hesitate to [edit] those details into your question! Remember the more you add, the more likely it is someone will be able to find this for you.

Comment: Animated or live action? Language?

Comment: I'm calling dibs. Rocket Full of Monkeys is the name of my new Devo cover band.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Possibly *Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow* (2004)

It's got giant robots with a diesel punk look to them, and the end has a rocket full of animals.

Comment: That was my thought as well, though I wasn't sure about the ending.  The giant robots and bat-like planes definitely fit.

Comment: What an amazingly bad film !